# Software to simulate attacks such man-in-the-middle or DoS

Tags: network, attacks

Sorry for novice question. I am completely new here.....

I am already familiar with Asp.net, JavaScript, Java, C++, etc.

I know the theories behind attacks and protocols, but I want to see them in simulation systems.

**Do you know any simulators where I can try these (network attacks such as DOS, man in middle) on them?**

Comment: In Android environments? Workstation?

Comment: check out GoatDroid:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Projects/OWASP_GoatDroid_Project

Comment: @schroeder of course not.

Comment: @mcgyver5 thanks, but i am looking for the simulator  as real world and not for Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one way of answering your question, you can look at something like [Kali Linux](http://www.kali.org/) , for a suite of attacks, and [Metasploitable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/metasploitable/files/Metasploitable2/) for a vulnerable target. Place both in a virtual environment (VirtualBox?) and simulate the types of attacks that you want.

Alternatively, you don't need a specialized target, but simply a generic target using a vanilla OS.